# iOS-How to set the clickable area of a custom UITableViewCell and its action of selection?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I'm writing a custom `UITableViewCell` shown as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKBZf.png

the cell consists of a timeLabel and messageView.I wanna have only the area of `messageView` is clickable.What should I do?

Much appreciation for every answer.

Comment: Does your timelabel has a gesture?

Comment: adding gesture may not make trick, may create problem for didSelect, try taking a same frame button on it

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: @SahebRoy no gesture.

Comment: are you doing anything in tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexpath?

Comment: @preetam you mean a transparent button that has the same frame of the messageView and make the button cover the messageView?

Comment: @SahebRoy only `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`